# What is the proper way of calling a method in Groovy

Tags: groovy, method-call

In fact, my issue is a lot broader than I could explain in the title. I'm having a problem with understanding a code in Groovy that's supposed to be fairly easy to understand. Please have a look at the following piece of code.

```
// event handlers are passed the event itself
1:def contactHandler(evt) {
2:    log.debug "$evt.value"
3:
4:  // The contactSensor capability can be either "open" or "closed"
5:  // If it's "open", turn on the light!
6:  // If it's "closed" turn the light off.
7:  if (evt.value == "open") {
8:      switch1.on();
9:  } else if (evt.value == "closed") {
10:      switch1.off();
11:  }
12:}
```

I can understand everything starting that falls after the line 2, but If lines 8 or 10 are the proper way of calling a method, then what the heck is going on in the line 2? I can understand that log.debug means "debug" function of the class called "log".(Or something similar) But what is that blank space after it? And more than that, why does it say "$evt.value", when it can simply say "evt.value" in lines 8 and 10? And why isn't there a semicolon at the end of the line. I know, they're optional, but as far as I can see there's a convention as to when to use them and when to not. And lastly, I have a stranger line of code which totally insane (to me of course):

```
    11: section ("When the door opens/closes...") {
    12: input "contact1", "capability.contactSensor",
    13:       title: "Where?"
    14: }
```

How should I understand the line starting from 12?

I've taken a look at http://groovy.codehaus.org/ but couldn't decide what to look for in order to find an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so from the beginning:

1. In groovy you can omit parentheses `()` when calling a method with arguments. So

   ```
   log.debug 'lol'
   ```

   is exactly the same as:

   ```
   log.debug('lol')
   ```

   Since `on()` and `off()` don't have any arguments, there's a **need** to use parens - or they might be mistaken with `on` and `off` **fields**. Blank separates method from arguments.
2. `evt.value` vs `"$evt.value"` - it's not the same. First is just a literal string, the second one is `GString`. First will print *evt.value* while the second one will evaluate the value of `value` variable for `evt` object. It might *open* or *closed* as further code shows.
3. Semicolon is optional, that's all I can say. No idea why semicolons are there. Sometimes there's a need to use semicolon - in oneliners e.g.

   ```
   items.collect { print it; it*it }
   ```
4. Starting from line no.12 it's also a method call. It's equal to:

   ```
   input("contact1", "capability.contactSensor", title: "Where?")
   ```

   It's passing a map as the first parameter, and then two strings as the second and third parameters.

Further reading:

1. [Methods](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_methods) - look also for *named parameters*.
2. [Optionality](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_optionality)
3. [All docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/)

Comment: #4 isn't a named method argument, it's passing a map as the first parameter, and then two strings as the second and third parameters. Otherwise, +1 ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Opal, for a quick and all encompassing answer.